# powershell comparing string with -or

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to verify the value of a variable, but no mater what, I can only get the right result if not using the -or

```
if (!$SER -eq "Y" -or  !$SER -eq "N"){
    write-host "ERROR: Wrong value for services restart" -foreground "red"
}
```

or like this

```
if (-not($SER -eq "Y") -or  -not($SER -eq "N")){
    write-host "ERROR: Wrong value for services restart" -foreground "red"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works (`ne` stands for *not equal*):

```
if ($SER -ne "Y" -or $SER -ne "N") {
    Write-Host "ERROR: Wrong value for services restart" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

This also works:

```
if ("Y", "N" -notcontains $SER) {
    Write-Host "ERROR: Wrong value for services restart" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

And since PowerShell v3:

```
if ($SER -notin "Y", "N") {
    Write-Host "ERROR: Wrong value for services restart" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

[about_Comparison_Operators (v3)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759(v=wps.620).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[sodawillow provided a valid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38012152/1163423). Howevery, you can simplify this using `-notin`:

```
if ($SER -notin 'Y', 'N') {
    Write-Host "ERROR: Wrong value for services restart" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```